# Void, value, or other?

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm working on a spaghetti monster (unfortunately not of the flying variety), and I've got a question about proper design.

I'm in the process of taking a gigantic static Java method that returns an object and splitting it into reusable (and readable) components.  Right now, the method reads an XML document, and then appends summary and detailed information from the document to a "dataModule", and the dataModule is then returned from the method.

In breaking my code up into a getSummaryData and getDetailedData method, I noticed I'd done the following:

```
dataModule = getSummaryData(xmlDocument);
setDetailedData(xmlDocument, dataModule);
```

(Pass by reference, append detailed data to dataModule within method)

This mostly has to do with the fact that the detailed data requires business logic based on the summary data in order to be parsed properly, and the fact that changing the structure of the dataModule involves lots of changing the front end of the application.

Is this approach any better than:

```
dataModule = getSummaryData(xmlDocument);
dataModule = setDetailedData(xmlDocument, dataModule);
```

(Pass by reference, append detailed data to dataModule within method, return dataModule)

I can't share much more of the code without revealing "teh secretz", but is there a strong reason to go with one approach over the other?  Or, am I just getting caught up in which shade of lipstick I'm putting on my pig, here?

Thanks,
IVR Avenger

Comment: The second form makes me want to write: dataModule = setDetailedData(xmlDocument, getSummaryData(xmlDocument)); although it looks a bit strange to have xmlDocument in there twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find your second approach, where you return the same object, more confusing - because it implies to the calling function that a different object might be returned.  If you're modifying the object, your first solution looks fine to me.

Comment: I agree, the second approach does look like you might be returning another object of the same type.

Comment: Of the two choices, the first is less confusing.  I assume you can't change the DataModule code.  If you *can* change it, I think Jonathan's idea of combining the two functions inside DataModule would probably be even better, given the limited info we have.

Answer (score 1):

One principle I'd use to answer your question is that you want as many things as possible to be `final`, so that you have less trouble reasoning about state. By that principle, you'd want to avoid a meaningless reassignment.

```
final DataModule dataModule = getSummaryData(xmlDocument);
setDetailedData(xmlDocument, dataModule);
```

But that's wrong too. Why should the summary and detailed data be separate steps? Will you ever do one without the other? If not, those steps should be private to the DataModule. Really, the data module should probably know how to construct itself from the xml data.

```
final DataModule dataModule = new DataModule(xmlDocument);
```

Comment: If for some reason setDetailedData does need to be separate, it should probably still be a method on DataModule, so you can do dataModule.setDetailedData(xmlDocument)

Comment: What you're describing in the last code example is what, given infinite time, I'd like to do.  Unfortunately, changing the dataModule can't be done at this point, given the time crunch I'm currently experiencing.  Over the course of supporting this app, I'm going to have to rewrite most of this and related classes, so I can always do that in the future.  I'm just trying to get some validation on this week's hack. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The (arguable) advantage of the second approach is that it permits method chaining.

Say you had, in addition to `setDetailedData()`, `setMoreData()`, and that both functions were written to return the object. You could then write:

```
dataModule = getSummaryData(xmlDocument);
dataModule = dataModule.setDetailedData(xmlDocument).setMoreData();
```

I don't think the example you've provided benefits much from a method chaining syntax, but there are examples where it can lead to truly beautiful, expressive code.  It permits what Martin Fowler calls a [Fluent Interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).